# Imposing Condition on a Cauchy Product

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, cauchy-product

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function with Fourier coefficients given by $\hat{f}$. Then, since $|f|^2 = f \cdot \bar{f}$, we have:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(k)|^2 \mathrm{d}k = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left( \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} \hat{f}(a)e^{iak} \right)\left( \sum_{b=0}^{\infty} \hat{f}(b)e^{-ibk} \right)\mathrm{d}k.$$

Using the Cauchy product, we obtain:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{c}\hat{f}(l)\hat{f}(c-l)e^{i(l - c + l)k}\mathrm{d}k.$$

Now, the integral is zero unless $2l = c,$ in which case, integrating the exponential term (the only part of the series which depends on $k$), gives us $2\pi.$ Imposing this condition leads to the sum:

$$\displaystyle 2\pi \sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{c}(\hat{f}(l))^2.$$

My question is this: can we do anything more here, using the condition that $2l = c$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering_and_physics

Comment: @user1952009 I assume that $f$ is periodic and in $L^2([0,2\pi])$. Note that the Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n)$ are indexed by $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and not by $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ so the sums in the first expression should run from $-\infty$ to $-\infty$. Then, the terms in the product look like $\hat{f}(a)e^{iak} \overline{\hat{f}(b)} e^{-ibk} = \hat{f}(a) \overline{\hat{f}(b)} e^{ik(a - b)}$ and the integral of each such term is zero unless $a = b$ in which case it is $2\pi |\hat{f}(a)|^2$ and so...